# How to make Space behave like Shift while Ctrl is held down? (Like at-home-modifier except Space behaves normally on press-down)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input

Basically, how could I turn Ctrl+Space into Ctrl+Shift while Space alone works normally?

I don't mind if the solution also involves other combinations of [Key]+Space to [Key]+Shift as long as Space *alone* sends a space character when **pressed down**.

I've tried using both `at-home-modifier` and `xcape` to make this work but they only send a space character when the Space key is **released** and not when pressed down, thus making it difficult to quickly type a normal sentence.

I'd prefer to avoid usage of `xmodmap` and `setxkbmap` as they don't support USB keyboard hotplugging.